# PHP CLI, WGET and CURL. Which one get better CPU/RAM performance using cronjob?

Tags: php, cron

I'm setting several cronjobs for PHP scripts so I want to know which option is better to CPU/RAM performance. I have a CentOS 7.3 server

Comment: Do some testing. There are other functions for making requests.

Comment: You're explaining too little for a generalized answer. Best to [trace it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with PHP CLI, less overhead.

I run a few crontasks myself and just sticking the following in your crontab (changed to use your files of course) makes it simple.

```
php -f /var/www/cron.php
```

You can run some tests to confirm it's better for you though - see which one runs quicker and uses less memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please, the "-f" option what means?